# Python doesn't work - "Program 'python.exe' failed to run"

Tags: python, python-3.x

After trying to copy a file with Google Chrome logins using a Python program, the antivirus issued a warning about a threat, and the next time it was launched, it gives the following error on the command line:

```
Program 'python.exe' failed to run: The file cannot be accessed by the systemAt line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message `+ CategoryInfo : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException`

It is likely that your antivirus made a mistake that saw your Python executable as a virus and removed it.

Simple uninstall and reinstall the Python from the official website and add that new executable to the whitelist of your antivirus should fix the issue.